# Copy a file with Ansible if it doesn't exist

Tags: ansible

I've seen the question asked in a round about sort of way but not conclusively answered. What I want to do is straight forward. I want to copy a file `index.php` to the remote host at `/var/www/index.php` but only if it doesn't already exist.

I've tried using `creates` and `only_if` but I don't think these are intended for the purpose I want here. Can anyone supply some examples of how I would go about this?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Assuming `index.php` exists in the role's `files` subdirectory:

```yaml
- copy: 
    src: index.php 
    dest: /var/www/index.php 
    force: no
```

The decisive property is `force`. As [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) explains, the default is `yes`, which will replace the remote file when contents are different than the source. If `no`, the file will only be transferred **if the destination does not exist**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have this: `  copy: src="{{ templates_dir }}/nginx/index.php" dest=/var/www/index.php owner=vagrant` but it overwrites every time.

Comment: But thank you. Your link helped as I found by setting force to false it is not overwritten. Something must be setting the default to force=true somewhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, my answer was incorrect. You're right, "force" defaults to yes and you have to set it to "no". I've updated the answer and it should hopefully be correct now.

Comment: To create an empty file (eg for logs) you can do `copy: content="" dest=/var/www/index.php force=no`

Comment: Creating empty files can also be done using `file: path=/var/log/file.log state=touch mode="u=rw,g=r,o=r"`

Comment: Does `copy` have a similar property that skips the copy if the source does not exist?